# How To Copy File From SD to Local Storage on Android

Tags: java, android, copy, android-4.4-kitkat

I know with Kit Kat you can only write to your applications package specific directory on SD Cards.  I was however under the impression you could still copy files from an SD card to local storage with the:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I am simply testing if I can copy one file.  If I am able to do that I will add the code to search the entire SD card DCIM folder.  For now I have the following code (please forgive the messiness of the code, I have written C# and vb.net but java is still very new to me):

```
String dirPath = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "TCM";
            File projDir = new File(dirPath);
            if (!projDir.exists())
                projDir.mkdirs();
            String CamPath = projDir + File.separator + tv2.getText();
            File projDir2 = new File(CamPath);
            if (!projDir2.exists())
                projDir2.mkdirs();
            File LocalBuck = new File(projDir2 + File.separator );

            String imageInSD = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
            File directory1 = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM");
            File directory = new File(directory1 + "/100SDCIM");
            File Buckfile = new File(directory, "/BigBuck.jpg");


            try {
                exportFile(Buckfile, LocalBuck);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Here is my code for the export function/application:

```
 private File exportFile(File src, File dst) throws IOException {

     //if folder does not exist
     if (!dst.exists()) {
         if (!dst.mkdir()) {
             return null;
         }
     }

     String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
     File expFile = new File(dst.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
     FileChannel inChannel = null;
     FileChannel outChannel = null;

     try {
         //Straight to Error Handler
         inChannel = new FileInputStream(src).getChannel();
         outChannel = new FileOutputStream(expFile).getChannel();
     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }

     try {
         inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel);
     } finally {
         if (inChannel != null)
             inChannel.close();
         if (outChannel != null)
             outChannel.close();
     }

     return expFile;
 }
```

Here is what my emulator looks like:
Looking for: [Debug of SD Location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBqtq.png)

Should Find It?: [EmulatorShowingSd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OH0r0.png)

Question: Am I even able to copy a file from the SD card to local storage after KitKat; if so what is wrong in the code causing the exception to be thrown when it tries to access the SD card file?